# Установка приложения по прямой ссылке

Tags: android

Пока нет возможности разместить программу в гугл плей. 
Если поместить программу куда-нить на хостинг, то программа сначала скачивается, затем пользователь с помощью менеджера должен найти этот apk файл и установить. 
МОжно ли ка-нибудь сделать так, чтобы программа скачивалась, и сразу начиналась установка?

Ссылку помещаю в qr-код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень то это рекомендуется, но сделать это можно.

Как известно, имеется специальный URI типа

```
market://id=my.application.package
```

который отрабатывает локально установленное на телефоне приложение Play Market. Фактически тип URI `market` является маркером по которому распознается соответствующий `Intent` установщика, который запускает Play Market.

Ломать так ломать: совершенно аналогично вы можете определить свой собственный тип URI, например:

```
<a href="mymarket://my.myhost.ru/my.application.package">Установить приложение</a>
```

по которому может запускаться ваше `Activity`, например:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="mymarket" android:host="my.host.ru" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Ну а уж внутри `Activity` вы можете скрыть скачивание и установку приложения от бедного юзера. Естессно вам понадобятся соответствующие пермишены.

Comment: Во-первых,

> Пока нет возможности разместить программу в гугл плей

Во-вторых,

> [Программы для Android запретили обновлять в обход Google Play][1]

  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/178551/

Comment: @fori1ton по поводу ссылки, вы бы прочитали внимательно статью :)

Comment: @fori1ton запретили обновление на уровне лицензии, но никак не на уровне технической возможности :)

Comment: @Barmaley, на уровне технической возможности вообще много чего можно сделать. Но за нарушение соглашения программу могут удалить из маркета. Вопрос: нужны ли ТС такие проблемы?

Answer (score 2):

Конечно нет! Это была бы огромнейшая дыра в безопасности! Представьте, что было бы, если бы приложение можно было установить просто перейдя по левой ссылке. Телефон мгновенно заплолнили бы тысячи вирусов.

Кстати, не обязательно искать apk в файловом менеджере, в большинстве браузеров есть менеджер загрузок, из коророго можно открыть любой скачанный файл.

Comment: Не надо быть таким категоричным...

Answer (score 1):

Конечно же нельзя. И, надеюсь, такой возможности никогда не будет.

Comment: Увы можно...

Comment: >чтобы программа скачивалась, и сразу начиналась установка?

И:

>Естессно вам понадобятся соответствующие пермишены.

Есть разница? Даже не так: IMHO, разница очевидна :)

Comment: Смотрим на то как устроен Amazon Market или Samsung Market там то же самое, только вместо Play Market кастомный маркет. Не вижу причин почему юзер не может себе сделать свой маленький маркет. Далеко не ходим и смотрим на Navitel